# Spark SQL filter multiple fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What is the corrent syntax for filtering on multiple columns in the Scala API? If I want to do something like this:

```
dataFrame.filter($"col01" === "something" && $"col02" === "something else")
```

or

```
dataFrame.filter($"col01" === "something" || $"col02" === "something else")
```

EDIT:

This is what my original code looks like. Everything comes in as a string.

```
df.select($"userID" as "user", $"itemID" as "item", $"quantity" cast("int"), $"price" cast("float"), $"discount" cast ("float"), sqlf.substring($"datetime", 0, 10) as "date", $"group")
  .filter($"item" !== "" && $"group" !== "-1")
```

Comment: Looks OK. Do you experience any problems?

Comment: If it doesn't work, you might just be missing `import sqlContext.implicits._`, where `sqlContext` is an instance of `SQLContext` or `HiveContext`.

Comment: I was getting "value && is not a member of String". Solution is to wrap each statement in a parenthesis.

Comment: @gstvolvr Both the above filters are working for me. To further debug this, it would help if you could post some previous code or the sample data.

Comment: @dheee I posted an edit. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think i see what the issue is. For some reason, spark does not allow two !='s in the same ***filter***. Need to look at how ***filter*** is defined in Spark source code.

Now for your code to work, you can use this to do the filter

```
df.filter(col("item").notEqual("") && col("group").notEqual("-1"))
```

or use two filters in same statement

```
df.filter($"item" !== "").filter($"group" !== "-1").select(....)
```

This link [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#notEqual(java.lang.Object)) can help with different spark methods.

Comment: Hi @dheee ? Do you know if both options perform the same?

Comment: @servatj I haven't seen any difference in performance on my end.

Comment: !== in class Column is deprecated and !== does not have the same precedence as ===. so i recon to use =!= instead.

Comment: @user3252097 can you post your query here.